# strange behaviour of sed command

Tags: bash, sed, solaris

Could anyone please explain this behaviour of `sed` ?

```
cat -bash-3.2# cat tmp7

echo "this is the song that never ends
yes, it goes on and on, my friend
some people started singing it
not knowing what it was
and they'll continue singing it forever
just because..." >
```

```
-bash-3.2# sed -n 's_.*some\(.*\)started.*_\1_p' tmp7
```

outputs

```
people
```

```
-bash-3.2# cat tmp8
echo "this is the song that never endsyes, it goes on and on, my friendsome people started singing itnot knowing what it wasand they'll continue singing it foreverjust because..." >

sed -n 's_.*some\(.*\)started.*_\1_p' tmp8
```

outputs nothing

I am expecting that output of second command should be equal to the first one.

The content of the files `tmp7` and `tmp8` are the same, only difference is that the tmp7 contains newline and tmp8 doesn't.

**UPDATE**

Tried with the different version of sed `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed`, getting desirable output but with a warning `sed: Missing newline at end of file tmp8.`. I would like the output without warning.

```
  /usr/xpg4/bin/sed -n 's_.*some\(.*\)started.*_\1_p' tmp8

   sed: Missing newline at end of file tmp8.
   people
```

Comment: Works for me. What version of `sed` do you have? can you show the `xxd` of the input files?

Comment: How can I find out the version of `sed`?

Comment: `sed --version
sed: illegal option -- version`

However when I am using the below command, I am getting the output, but with a warning.

`/usr/xpg4/bin/sed -n 's_.*some\(.*\)started.*_\1_p' tmp8

 `sed: Missing newline at end of file tmp8`
 `people`

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: I have updated the question after some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris default `sed` ignores the last line not to break existing scripts  because a line was required to be terminated by a new line in the original Unix implementation.

GNU `sed` has a more relaxed behavior and the POSIX implementation accept the fact but outputs a warning. You can redirect stderr to /dev/null to ignore it.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/sed -n 's_.*some\(.*\)started.*_\1_p' tmp8 2>/dev/null
```